# Give an example that two DAGs are in the same Markov equivalent class, but the number of edges are different.

Tags: graph-theory

Can you give me an example that two DAGs are in the same Markov equivalent class, but the number of edges are different. DAG mean directed acyclic graph.

I read a paper that mentioned about minimal-edge I-MAP which means a DAG with a minimal number of edges (and it may not be unique) in same Markov equivalence class.

But I cannot find a concrete example that say 2 DAGs with different number of edges but share the same Markov equivalent class.